# If statement is not used

Tags: if-statement, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have following code in Groovy:

```
seedGerritHost = config.seedgerrit?.host
println "seedGerritHost: " + seedGerritHost
if (seedGerritHost == null) {
    seedGerritHost = config.gerrit.host.toString()
    print "seedGerritHost was null, now its: " + seedGerritHost
}
...
def predefineJobs = new File("/usr/share/jenkins/predefineJobs")
def newPredefineJobs = predefineJobs.text
    .replace("#projectName",config.jenkins.project.toString())
    .replace("#gerritHost",seedGerritHost.toString())
```

Object `config.seedgerrit?.host` is not defined so I assume that if statement must be executed but it's not.

Null pointer exception is throwing in logs:

```
seedGerritHost: null
seedGerritPort: null
2020-02-14 18:29:28.381+0000 [id=25]    WARNING j.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript#execute: 
Failed to run script file:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/04.jobs.groovy
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2240)
    at java_lang_String$replace$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at 04_jobs.run(04.jobs.groovy:27)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.execute(GroovyHookScript.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.execute(GroovyHookScript.java:127)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.run(GroovyHookScript.java:110)
    at hudson.init.impl.GroovyInitScript.init(GroovyInitScript.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1119)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Null pointer exception is related to `.replace("#gerritHost",seedGerritHost)` line. `seedGerritHost` is null because if statement wasn't executed for some reason.

Comment: could it be that `config.seedgerrit?.host` - literal value `"null"`

Comment: I don't think so. In other code there's parser for yaml settings file. It could two states, one is that `config.seedgerrit?.host` is set to some IP (as string); or there's no value at all. So `config.seedgerrit?.host` should set null because there's no value like that.

Comment: Since `null.toString()` evaluates to `"null"` in groovy 3.0.0 and `String.replace()` raises an NPE when the second argument is null, the likely reason for the NPE is `seedGerritHost.toString()` evaluates to `null`.  BTW, what is the value of `seedGerritHost` after the `if` block?

Comment: `04_jobs.run(04.jobs.groovy:27)` check this... i think it is not from `if` command

Comment: @Venkatesh-PrasadRanganath still null because `if` statement doesn't work

Comment: @BhanuchanderUdhayakumar of course. It's from .replace method.

Comment: @QkiZ When the then-block of the `if` statement is not executed,  `seedGerritHost` should be non-null.  As I mentioned in my previous comment, `String.replace()` raises NPE when the second arg is `null`.  So, I suspect `seedGerritHost` is non-null but `seedGerritHost.toString()` evaluates to `null`.  Please check the nullness of `seedGerritHost` and `seedGerritHost.toString()` via equality check.

Comment: @Venkatesh-PrasadRanganath println shows that seedGerritHost is null. This is set by `config.seedgerrit?.host`. or it should be.

Comment: @QkiZ The outcome from `println` does not show `seedGerritHost == null` because `seedGerritHost.toString()` can evaluate to `"null"` if `seedGerritHost == null` or `seedGerritHost.toString() == null` or `seedGerritHost.toString() == "null"`.  You need to rule out the latter two possibilities to ascertain `seedGerritHost == null`.

Comment: show your `config` object